# How do I obtain a PPP cookie for rasdial API?

Tags: c#, winapi, vpn, ras

The [RASDIALEXTENSIONS structure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/aa377029(v%3Dvs.85)) defines:

> fSkipPppAuth
>
> Windows 7 or later: If this member is TRUE, then Point to Point Protocol (PPP) authentication is skipped and the value in RasDevSpecificInfo will be passed to the server for validation. Otherwise, this member is FALSE and PPP authentication proceeds normally.
>
> RasDevSpecificInfo
>
> Windows 7 or later: A RASDEVSPECIFICINFO structure
>   that contains a cookie to be used for PPP authentication. This cookie
>   is only valid if fSkipPppAuth is TRUE.

How would one go about obtaining this cookie? If I connect with the [rasdial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ras/nf-ras-rasdiala) function, how can I obtain a cookie to use for future connections?

Comment: `DWORD APIENTRY RasDialA( _In_opt_ LPRASDIALEXTENSIONS, _In_opt_ LPCSTR, _In_ LPRASDIALPARAMSA, _In_ DWORD,
                         _In_opt_ LPVOID, _Out_ LPHRASCONN );` `_In_opt_` means this is an optional **input** parameter, with no output value. You should specfied the cookie.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT yes I see how to provide it, but I'm trying to find out how to obtain the cookie to pass in. How is the original cookie generated?

Comment: Check if this API is useful: [`InternetGetCookieEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wininet/nf-wininet-internetgetcookieexa)